# Select path to Public Folder on modules in ZF2

Tags: module, frameworks, zend-framework2, public

I've a problem.
I have 2 module in my ZF2 project: Application, Search. I'm using layout folder/file.
When I use any Controller and Action on Application everything works fine. When I use Search module only loads public folder files on default Action.
On the other actions I have a url like http/mysite/search/css/mycss.css but I want http/mysite/css/mycss.css.

Is there anyway to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: My application.config.php

```
    <?php
    return array(
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'Feed',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineMongoODMModule',

),
  'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        './vendor',
    ),

    'config_glob_paths' => array(
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
    ),
),
  );
```

I'm sorry my module is called Feed not Search =)

EDIT 2: My route from Application Module

```
<?php

return array(
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'application' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/application',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
    ),
    'aliases' => array(
        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
    ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
        ),
    ),
),
);
```

EDIT 3: My route from Feed Module

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Feed\Controller\Feed' => 'Feed\Controller\FeedController',
        ),
      ),

    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'feed' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/feed[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Feed\Controller\Feed',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),      
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'feed' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Have you enabled the Search module in `config/application.config.php` per [docs](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/modules.html)?

Comment: yeah, it's there
modules' => array(
        'Application',
     'Search',
), ...
And my page router seems to be fine, loads the layout but the problem is the link that includes my module name that doesn't let me load my css or js files correctly

Comment: Should I configure something in my Module.php file? I guess perhaps it's something about the NAMESPACE to give the correct path to public folder

Comment: Maybe edit the question to include your `application.config.php` and all routes. We'll probably need all that to reproduce/diagnose.

Comment: Probably need routes, too. After all, it is a routing question. :P

Comment: Ok, I've added my complete module.config.php from both module I'm using. Hope it helps.

Comment: Any ideas? if I change my default in router/routes/feed/option/defaults, the action I put as default loads fine like "http/mysite/css/mycss.css" but the others use "http/mysite/search/css/mycss.css"